# Get average review star rating score in text

Tags: php, html, review

I want to echo the average review star rating of a product in text.

Currently it is displayed in width % to display the review stars.

But I want to display it like:

Reviewscore is 4.7 / 5

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line does echo the ratingscore into text:

```
<?php $ratingPercent = $this->getRatingSummary(); echo ($ratingPercent * 5)/100; ?>
```

Comment: Should be marked as "best answer" ;)

Answer (score 0):

`$ratingPercent = number_format($this->getRatingSummary() / 20,1);`